# Need help making Django + Ajax like button

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am new to coding and have currently implemented the like button from the online book - Tango with django:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html#add-a-like-button

However for my project I need to record which users have liked what and also ensure that they can only like an item once (similar to instagram/facebook). I have looked at other related questions online but have found that there is no well laid out answer for other beginners to follow. If someone could do an easy to follow answer to help me and other people who are trying to achieve the same in the future, it would be greatly appreciated!

my current code is as follows:

models

```
class UserProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    project_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

views

```
@login_required
def like_project(request):

    proj_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        proj_id = request.GET['project_id']

    likes = 0
    if proj_id:
        proj = UserProject.objects.get(id=int(proj_id))
        if proj:
            likes = proj.project_likes + 1
            proj.project_likes = likes
            proj.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

template

```
<strong id="like_count">{{ project.project_likes }}</strong> likes

          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <button id="likes" data-projid="{{project.id}}" class="btn btn-danger-outline btn-sm" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                  like
                  </button>
          {% endif %}
```

URL

```
url(r'^like_project/$', views.like_project, name='like_project'),
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#likes').click(function(){
    var projid;
    projid = $(this).attr("data-projid");
    $.get('/like_project/', {project_id: projid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure no `User` likes the same `UserProject` twice, you can not simply store the number of likes in the `project_likes` field, but you should rather create a separate model (e.g. `UserLikes`) with `ForeignKeys` to `User` and `UserProject`, and e.g. the time at which the User liked the `UserProject`. You can then make a function on your `UserProject` model to count the number of likes.

Comment: thanks, I know I will need a new model for the likes but don't quite understand how I need to change the Ajax and view to accommodate it.

Comment: Start by amending the view; create a new UserLike object there.